# Does chmod() need leading zeroes to work properly?

Tags: c, chmod, atoi

I'm trying to call the `chmod()` function from my C program, but it
isn't setting the correct permissions unless the `mode_t` argument has
leading zeroes in it. For example `chmod(argv[2],00777)` will work,
but `chmod(argv[2],777)` will set the permissions to complete garbage.

The big problem comes when I try to use `atoi()` because it will 
discard any leading zeroes. Is there any way I can make the following
program work even if the user enters a value with no leading zeroes
in the command line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{  
    if (argc != 3)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (chmod(argv[2], (mode_t)atoi(argv[1])) != 0)
        printf("Warning: Unable to change file permissions.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read a basic tutorial for a language you are trying to use before using it. Most C tutorials mention early on that numbers literals starting with 0 are interpreted as octal (base 8).

Comment: `0777` and `777` are simply two different integer values. `0777 == 511`; `777 == 01411`. `chmod` happens to interpret its mode argument as a bit pattern in groups of 3 bits. Octal happens to be the most convenient way to represent such a value.

Comment: the chmod second argument is expected to be an octal value.  To declare an octal value in C, the number must have a leading 0.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the zero is necessary, unless you convert the number into the correct base ahead of time. A leading zero in an integer literal makes C read the number in octal, in the same way that `0x` makes it read the integer in hexadecimal. If you use `strtol`, you can provide a `base` parameter of 8 to read an integer in octal.

Answer (score 2):

A leading zero means that the number is in octal representation, not in decimal (so e.g. 0777 = 7 * 64 + 7 * 8 + 7 = 511 in decimal). You can use `strtol` instead of `atoi`, where you can also prescribe the base (8 in this case).